# Dynamics 365 Web API giving 401 error?

Tags: oauth-2.0, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I was trying out Microsoft Dynamics 365 (v9.0) Web APis. 
I was able to generate access token but yet my api call is failing.
I am using `adal` for python

```
from adal import AuthenticationContext
import requests

api = 'https://xxxxxx.crm8.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/'

auth_context = AuthenticationContext('https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxx.com')


token = auth_context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(
    resource='https://xxxxxx.com/0d74ff2f-d7d2-46f4-a3c3-fb4f6d49aa51',
    client_id='6e859f06-0d88-413f-a3fe-1ae12cc7350d',
    client_secret='abigclientsecret')

print(token)

at = 'Bearer ' + token['accessToken']

headers = {'Authorization' : at,
"Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
'OData-MaxVersion' :'4.0',
'OData-Version' :'4.0',
'Accept' : 'application/json'}
response = requests.get("https://xxxxxx.api.crm8.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/contacts", headers=headers)
print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Organization URI like below: (removed `.api.` from your snippet)

```
response = requests.get("https://xxxxxx.crm8.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/contacts", headers=headers)
```

I see you have initialized a variable called `api = 'https://xxxxxx.crm8.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/'` which is correct but you have not used it.

Comment: Yet it is giving me <Response 401>

Comment: @AtulK. Silly question. Did you register your crmol in AAD & got this clientid & secret?

Comment: Yes. I did. In fact, I am getting Access token too. But when I do get call it is giving Error 401: Unauthorised access.

Comment: @AtulK. did you find the answer for this. I am having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you given consent for the user over the required resource?
Refer to the link below and look under "Request an authorization code".
You will need to add the 'prompt' parameter with 'consent' as the value.
Azure AD will then decide to take you to a consent page if consent has not yet been granted.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code